# Syntax error upgrading compatibility level SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

We have some SQL Server 2005 DB's that we are preparing for an upgrade. As part of this a number of them have their compatibility_levels set to 80 and so I need to change them to at least 90.

I'm using the following TSQL Syntax to upgrade each DB via a script:

```
ALTER DATABASE DbName
SET compatibility_level = 90
Go
```

But I receive an Error:

**Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near '90'.**

Any ideas what Is wrong would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For SQL Server 2005 I believe you need to use this stored procedure:

```
EXEC dbo.sp_dbcmptlevel @dbname=N'DbName', @new_cmptlevel=90
GO
```